# Visual C++ 2015 gives C4552 warning when used decltype( auto )

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I think I've encountered a bug in Visual C++ 2015 but I want to be sure. Consider this snippet:

```cpp
template < typename T >
decltype( auto ) f( T param )
{
    return param + 1;
}

int main()
{
    auto i = f( 10 );
    return 0;
}
```

Visual C++ 2015 gives this warning on the return statement:

> warning C4552: '+': operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect

though it seems it doesn't have any impact on the resulting code. Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: I would have to say so.  I can replicate it on my VS2015 but I get the correct output.  [g++ will compile the code without any warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6c4085223ae9e64).  VS will also issue the warning if you change the return to `1 + param`

Comment: Same for VS2017: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/209671/wrong-warning-c4552-with-decltypeauto.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. It has an open bug report here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1468881/decltype-auto-causes-unnecessary-warnings

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in [Csq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31966067/1889329) already, the observed behavior has a [pending Microsoft Connect report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1468881/decltype-auto-causes-unnecessary-warnings). The issue has not yet been evaluated.

To work around the issue<sup>1)</sup>, you can include parentheses around the expression:

```
template < typename T >
decltype( auto ) f( T param )
{
    return ( param + 1 );
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Verified using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition*

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Microsoft itself [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/577cze47.aspx), it might be "mistake". Try with:

```
decltype(auto) f(T param)
{
    return (param + 1);
}
```

Or just suppress this warring because Microsoft probably won't fix it due to their "mistake" excuse.

Comment: "as the top of the expression" - that's not the top of the expression, that's inside a return

Comment: This is unrelated to the question. Issuing a warning on an **expression statement** like `i+j;` is perfectly sane. This is expected behavior, and needs no fix. The question is asking about a `return` statement containing an expression. Your proposed solution, however, happens to apply to the original question as well.